# How to draw a pyramid according to the requirements?

Tags: graphics3d

In the pyramid P-ABCD, the bottom surface ABCD is a diamond, AC intersects with BD at point O, the angle BAD is equal to 60 °, PA=AB=2, PA vertical AC, plane PAC vertical plane PBD, and M is the point on the line segment PB

The appearance of a four-dimensional figure is as follows:

[image]

I am trying to solve the problem step by step, and I welcome your guidance

1. Draw a pyramid with the intersection point of the bottom diamond diagonal as the origin of the spatial coordinate system：

```
Graphics3D[
 Pyramid[{{Sqrt[3], 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {-Sqrt[3], 0, 0}, {0, -1, 
    0}, {Sqrt[3], 0, 2}}]]
```

2. How to add the letters in the figure to each vertex next?

Comment: Please show the code you have tried so far. There is a function [`Pyramid`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pyramid.html).

Comment: The definition of `M` isn't unique.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann The M-point does not require fixation, as long as it can be moved within the segment

Comment: @Domen This command is not very convenient for drawing. If the origin of the space Cartesian coordinate system system is not the vertex of a solid figure, but the intersection of the midpoint of a line segment and the diagonal of the bottom polygon in practical application. Do you need to calculate the coordinates of other points on this basis when drawing?

Comment: I think, you can use [3dtools](https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools/blob/master/tikzlibrary3dtools.code.tex)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- We can solve the equations which according to the conditons to find the coordinate of the point `p`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
a = {0, 0, 0};
b = {2, 0, 0};
d = 2 {Cos[π/3], Sin[π/3], 0};
c = b + d;
p = {x, y, z};
p = SolveValues[{(p - a) . (a - c) == 0, 
    Cross[p - a, p - c] . Cross[p - b, p - d] == 0, Norm[p - a] == 2, 
    z > 0}, {x, y, z}] // First
m = Mean[{p, b}];
o = Mean[{a, b, c, d}];
labels = {Text[Style[P, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], p, {-1, -1}],
   Text[Style[A, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], a, {1, 1}],
   Text[Style[B, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], b, {1, 1}],
   Text[Style[C, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], c, {-2, 0}],
   Text[Style[D, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], d, {3, 0}],
   Text[Style[M, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], m, {-1, -2}],
   Text[Style[O, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], o, {0, 1}]};
Graphics3D[{Thick, Line[{p, a, b}], Line[{p, b, c, p}], 
  Line[{a, m, c}], Dashed, Line[{a, c}], Line[{b, d}], Line[{d, p}], 
  Line[{d, a}], Line[{d, c}], labels}, Boxed -> False, 
 ViewPoint -> {-.9, -3, 1.28}]
```

> `{0,0,2}`

[image]

Comment: First step: Calculate the coordinates of the four vertices on the bottom surface.

Comment: a = {0, 0, 0};
b = {2, 0, 0};
d = 2 {Cos[π/3], Sin[π/3], 0};
c = b + d;

Comment: Then the second step: Find the coordinates of the vertex P of the pyramid

Comment: ```Cross[p - a, p - c]``` and ```Cross[p - b, p - d]```Are these two finding the normal vectors of two planes separately? If the plane is perpendicular, then their normal vectors are perpendicular. Use a system of equations to find the coordinates of point P

Comment: ```Text[Style[P, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], p, {-1, -1}]```This sentence describes vertex attributes.   The vertex letter name is P，```FontFamily -> "Times"``this is a font，```p```This represents the coordinates of vertex P,``` {-1, -1}```How much offset is the vertex letter P at the coordinate position of vertex P?

Comment: Have I understood the above code correctly?

Comment: Among them, point M is a point on the line segment PB. That is to say, if the position of M on PB is uncertain, M point can be marked on PB. When the cursor reaches M point, M point can be moved to the PB line segment and the coordinate value of M can be displayed in real-time. Can this be achieved?

Comment: How to automatically add the x axis, y axis and z axis of the space Cartesian coordinate system system according to the selected coordinate origin?

Comment: How to color a certain plane? Or change the color of a certain or several line segments?