# How to find the cosine of dihedral angle on the premise of satisfying the line plane angle?

Tags: graphics3d

[How to draw a pyramid according to the requirements?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/285531/how-to-draw-a-pyramid-according-to-the-requirements)

The previous question was to draw a pyramid. Now the cosine value of the dihedral angle is required to meet the conditions after the quadrangular pyramid is drawn.

[image]

[image]

Among them, point M is a point on the line segment PB. When the sine value of the angle between AM and planar PBD is the maximum, find the cosine value of the angle between planar MAC and planar ABCD

Answer (score 0):

My own answer, I look forward to better solutions from everyone!

````
In[258]:= BM = t {p - b} // First

Out[258]= {-2 t, 0, 2 t}

In[259]:= M = BM + b

Out[259]= {2 - 2 t, 0, 2 t}

In[260]:= b

Out[260]= {2, 0, 0}

In[262]:= n1 = Cross[p - b, p - d]

Out[262]= {2 Sqrt[3], 2, 2 Sqrt[3]}

In[263]:= AM = M - a

Out[263]= {2 - 2 t, 0, 2 t}

In[266]:= Cos[VectorAngle[n1, AM]]

Out[266]= (
2 Sqrt[3] (2 - 2 Conjugate[t]) + 
 4 Sqrt[3] Conjugate[t])/(2 Sqrt[7] Sqrt[Abs[2 - 2 t]^2 + 4 Abs[t]^2])

In[267]:= Simplify[(
 2 Sqrt[3] (2 - 2 Conjugate[t]) + 4 Sqrt[3] Conjugate[t])/(
 2 Sqrt[7] Sqrt[Abs[2 - 2 t]^2 + 4 Abs[t]^2])]

Out[267]= (2 Sqrt[3/7])/Sqrt[Abs[2 - 2 t]^2 + 4 Abs[t]^2]

In[275]:= MAX = 
 Maximize[{(2 Sqrt[3/7])/Sqrt[Abs[2 - 2 t]^2 + 4 Abs[t]^2], 
    0 <= t <= 1}, t] // FullSimplify

Out[275]= {Sqrt[6/7], {t -> 1/2}}

In[281]:= MAX[[2]]

Out[281]= {t -> 1/2}

In[283]:= M = {2 - 2 t, 0, 2 t} /. MAX[[2]]

Out[283]= {1, 0, 1}

In[287]:= n2 = Cross[M - a, M - c]
n3 = Cross[a - b, a - c]

Out[287]= {Sqrt[3], -3, -Sqrt[3]}

Out[288]= {0, 0, 2 Sqrt[3]}

In[289]:= Cos[VectorAngle[n2, n3]]

Out[289]= -(1/Sqrt[5])
```
````